# (Novice) How to insert javascript gallery into HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

I'm trying to insert a free gallery slider called iDangerous slider into a website. The source consists of two files - one a .css file and one a .js file [source](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/tree/master/src).
However, I have absolutely no idea even how to begin to use it. I can't see how to insert it into the website's HTML, nor how to insert the images that the slider gallery will use. Many thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have any working knowledge of HTML? Does this slider provide any helpful information on installation?

Comment: @Varosion thank you for the link! I don't know how I missed it. I added it, and it's working now. However, I'm also trying to add arrows to the slider like in the [demo](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/). I'm trying to figure out whether the code for this is already included. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Varosion I apologies - I just don't think you understand how little I know about how any of this works. If you're still willing to help me (which I doubt you are) could you explain to me briefly exactly how to use the `mySwiper.swipeNext()` stuff. Do I make a new `var` or `div`? I'm really sorry- I'm absolutely clueless and I have to get this thing done pretty quickly

Comment: I'm really sorry to be useless again. I'm absolutely useless at computery shit but I have this pressure on me to get this done. So I took your advice and put the `div` in. This is what it looks like: `<div onclick="mySwiper.swipeNext();" style="cursor:pointer;"> NEXT </div>`  But it doesn't actually do anything, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Oops @Varosion please see my above comment